# SQL DATEDIFF predicate in WHERE clause not restricting results as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute the statement below so that only properties that were listed in the last 29 days show, but when I execute the command it's as if this gets ignored because properties from 2012 are showing. Have I over looked something?

**EDIT:** field type is smalldatetime

```
where DATEDIFF(DAY, ListedDate, GETDATE()) < 29
```

Comment: What is the data type of your ListedDate field ?

Comment: smalldatetime is the feild type

Comment: Two issues here. I assume that ListedDate is earlier than the current date? Your function is backwards. More importantly your predicate is nonSARGable. You wrapped your column in a function. We can turn this around so your predicate will be sargable.

Comment: @SeanLange iv never heard of them words before haha can you simplify and no the listed dates are years old and current date is today

Comment: Something like this. where ListedDate > DATEADD(day, -29, getdate())

Comment: It isn't about simplifying. SARGability = "search argumentable" which refers to the ability of the sql engine to utilize an index. When you wrap a column in a function you force the optimizer to use an index scan instead of an index seek. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: I think what you want is rows within the last 29 days? The post above should do that for you.

Comment: @SeanLange, I agree with you on SARGability.  What I don't understand is why the OP's where clause wouldn't work.  It works when I test it.  It isn't the best way but why isn't it getting the results wanted.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: Something like this. where ListedDate > DATEADD(day, -29, getdate()) this worked perfect! thanks p.s add it to the comments and ill give it a tick!

Comment: don't modify the data to suit a constant, change the constant to suit the data. another vote for the sargable approach

Comment: @user3083310 because the two date values are backwards in logic. How many days has it been since July 1, 2014? It isn't a negative value. select DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-07-01', GETDATE());

Comment: @SeanLange  Right.  But since he want only anything in the last 28 days, that should work.  The 1st is 10 days difference, so it would be less than 29 and should be returned.

Comment: True. My brain mostly ignored it because it needed to flipped around for sargability anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the answer that worked and was mentioned in the comments above. I decided to post it as an answer after the original poster never. This was to make it easier for other users to find.

```
where ListedDate > DATEADD(day, -29, getdate())
```

For details on why its the answer please read comments under original question